# Stored Procedure in Code First with different tables

Tags: stored-procedures

I am working with Code First and using EF 4.1. I have a doubt in using stored procedure. Suppose if my stored procedure is taking values from 2 or 3 tables, how would i get the result ? How i can retrieve the result ? what will be the type of the result ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think, with Code First approach you will be able to get the stored procedures. Actually Code First/Stored procedures is like oxymoron. Check out this blog:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-release-candidate-available.aspx

In this blog, see the section.

```
What’s Not in EF 4.1?
Stored Procedure support in Code First
```

Also there is a school of thought of not using stored procedures at all, Check out this blog, its quite interesting :)
http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2003/11/18/38178.aspx